# flask - how to redirect outside of app context

Tags: python, http, flask

I'm trying to do a simple redirect from a function that is not decorated with the @app decorator, how can I do this (presumably I need to make check_status() aware of the app context)?

```
def check_status():
    return redirect("http://google.com")

@dashboard_bp.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def website_users():
    check_status()
    return render_template('website_users.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context is active *globally*. When you call `check_status()` from `website_users()`, the context is active.

Not that the `redirect()` callable *needs* a context; all it does is produce a `Response()` object, for which no context is required.

You *are* ignoring the return value of `check_status()` however. Perhaps you need to check if `check_status()` is returning something:

```
status = check_status()
if status is not None:
    # redirect
    return status
```

Alternatively, make `check_status()` raise an exception. You can handle that exception in your view (and turn it into a redirect response there), or you can register an [`errorhandler()` function](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) to handle a dedicated exception:

```
class StatusDenied(Exception):
    pass

@app.errorhandler(StatusDenied)
def redirect_on_status_denied(error):
    return redirect("http://google.com")

def check_status():
    raise StatusDenied
```

Comment: Alternately, `check_status` could throw an error (and have a special error handler for it that performs the redirect).

Comment: @SeanVieira: I was getting to that. :-)

Comment: Ah yes, I was indeed ignoring the return value. I quite like the solution where I raise an error - how can I adapt this to work within a blueprint (I don't have access to @app)? thanks.

Comment: @L-R: Use [`Blueprint.errorhandler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.errorhandler) (so `@bprint.errorhandler()`) instead of `@app.errorhandler()`).